# Return NetSuite "tranid" When Adding a Sales Order

Tags: web-services, netsuite

Using the NetSuite web service I am creating a sales order. The result that comes back only contains the `internalId` for the sales order. The email that goes to the customer shows the `tranid` however (shown as the "Order Number"). Is there a way to return the `tranid` when creating the sales order so that I don't have to make a second API call to get the order details?

Comment: no, you can't. create record and then search back for tranid

Comment: Integrating with NetSuite is absolutely horrible. This is only one of many reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

simplest thing is to:

```
var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(soRec);
var tranId = nlapiLookupField('salesorder', id, 'tranid');
```